# Compute dot product of numpy arrays (3,) and (1,)

Tags: numpy, dot-product

I want to compute the dot product between two numpy arrays.
For example, my arrays have shape of (3,) and (1,), so from basic math understanding I should an vector of shape (3,1). However using numpy dot would not get the result like that. In general, my input would have the size of (x,n) and (n,x) and I would like to get the shape (x,x) or scalar if x=1.

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue here is that you're using arrays of size `(3,)` and `(1,)` but you should be using `(3,1)` and `(1,1)`. With that it behaves exactly as you want/expect:

```
>>> np.dot([3, 2, 1], [1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
>>> np.dot([[3], [2], [1]], [[1]])
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1]])
```

For `(x, n)` and `(n, x)` shapes:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> n = 4
>>> A = np.ones((x, n))
>>> B = np.ones((n, x))
>>> A.dot(B)
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
>>> A.dot(B).shape
(5, 5)
```

Again, exactly as you want/expect. Note that in numpy, an array with shape `(n,)` is a *zero* dimensional array, while an array with shape `(n,1)` is a *one* dimensional array. Single dimensional arrays are necessary for operations on them to behave like you would expect.